# Get data from antenna UHF ethernet port in python

Tags: python, pyserial

Hi i have an antenna UHF to read tags, i already have the program to receive the data by the serial port, but now im trying use the ethernet port, this is the program for the serial, how can i make it to the ethernet port? sorry im new in python

```
import serial, binascii
import time

ser = serial.Serial( # Configurar el puerto serial
    port='COM5', # Puerto COM1
    #baudrate=9600, # Baudios

    baudrate=115200, # Baudios
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, # Paridad
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, # Bits de parada
    #databits=serial.EIGHTBITS, # Bits de datos
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, # Tamaño de los bytes
    timeout=1 # Tiempo de espera
    
)


#ser.close() # Cerrar el puerto serial
#ser.open()  # Abrir el puerto serial

while 1: 
    #data = str(binascii.hexlify(ser.read(16))) # Leer los datos del puerto serial
    data = ser.read(25) # Leer los datos del puerto serial
    if data != "": # Si hay datos
       # print ("tag: {}".format(data[6:22])) # Imprimir los datos en hexadecimal
       
        print ("tag: %", data, end="\n" ) # Imprimir los datos en hexadecimal
        ser.flushInput() # Limpiar la cola de recepcion
    else: 
        print ("no hay tag")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.238', 7086)
sock.connect(server_address)

while True:
 data = self.sock.recv(4096)  
 if data:
  if len(data) > 10:
     data = str(binascii.hexlify(data)) 
     data = data[16:28] 
     print ("Card Scanned. Tag ID:", data)    
     if data not in lista:
      lista.append(data)
```